# On the Sieve of Sundaram

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-complexity, sieve-theory

I have an implementation of Sieve of Sundaram in C# that returns all odd primes as follows:

```
        public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> SieveOfSundaram(BigInteger n)
        {
            IEnumerable<BigInteger> Candidates()
            {
                for(BigInteger i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    for(BigInteger j = i; i + j + 2*i*j <= n ; j++)
                    {
                        var x = i + j + 2*i*j;
                        yield return x;
                    }
                }
            };

            IEnumerable<BigInteger> GenerateList()
            {
                for(BigInteger i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }

            IEnumerable<BigInteger> Sieve()
            {
                return GenerateList().Except(Candidates()).Select(x => x+x+1);
            }

            return Sieve();

        }
```

The [asymptotic complexity of the Sieve of Sundaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) is supposed to be $O(n \log n)$. However, I see that the `Candidates()` routine runs $O(n \log n)$ and the `GenerateList()` runs $O(n)$ and in my Sieve implementation, the set exclusion is done by the `GenerateList().Except(Candidates())` which would mean $O(n^2 \log n)$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The standard algorithm implementation uses space of $O(n)$ to perform the set exclusion operations to ensure time complexity of $O(n \log n)$. It does an $O(n \log n)$ pass to mark entries to skip and then does a separate $O(n)$ pass to return the odd primes.

Asymptotically, $O(n + n \log n) \approx O(n \log n)$.